# why do arrays behave differently in json when you push a value into them?

Tags: php, arrays, json, ajax

I need to use AJAX to pass database row id's and up to 4 values to update a MYSQL table. I store the values in separate arrays.

```
function chgavail($rlu_id, $val) { // 1 of 4 functions used to store the values
    var ix;
    ix = $.inArray($rlu_id, changearray); // See if this row is in the array
    if (ix < 0) { // If not found then add it
        changearray.push($rlu_id);
        ix = $.inArray($rlu_id, changearray);
        costarray[ix] = -1; // cost column }
        minarray[ix]  = -1; // min column  } "don't update" codes
        lockarray[ix] = 'X'; // lock column }
    }
    availarray[ix] = $val; // add the value to update
}

function postrates() {
    if (changearray.length > 0) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            async: true,
            url: "xml_postdailyrate.php",
            data: {
                'changearray': JSON.stringify(changearray),
                'minarray':    JSON.stringify(minarray),
                'lockarray':   JSON.stringify(lockarray),
                'costarray':   JSON.stringify(costarray),
                'availarray':  JSON.stringify(availarray)
            },
            success: function(JSON) {
                changearray = []; //clear arrays for next time
                availarray = [];
                costarray = [];
                minarray = [];
                lockarray = [];
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('Failed'); //Todo:
            }
        })
    }
}
```

The AJAX POST data  (reported by Firebug)

```
   availarray   ["1","1"]
   changearray  [111950,111951]
   costarray    ["999","888"]
   lockarray    ["L","L"]
   minarray     ["7","6"]
```

The problem I have been struggling with is when I make the AJAX call the "change" array is fine but I cannot decode the others successfully. They appear to be an array of an array of single characters.

```
   (Reported by Firefox)
   changearray   [111950, 111951]
         0   111950
         1   111951
   availarray     "["1","1"]"
   lockarray      "["L","L"]"
   costarray      "["999","888"]"
   minarray       "["7","6"]"
```

The generated SQL looks like this (the double quotes (") come from the arrays the single quotes, after ratelock, from my code)

```
UPDATE ratelookup SET qty2sell=", cost=", minnight=", ratelock='"' WHERE id= 111951
```

Please help I have spent all day googling and trying different ideas with no success.

Comment: Why do you JSON encode/decode? It is not necessary. jQuery will pass the object with pure arrays just fine to your server, where you will be able to access them just like that. Can you add to your question the PHP code you use to access the request arguments (in `$_GET`)?